# Which email address should the printed Case Report present for the Case Manager in the Role Section of the Report?

Tags: civicase

The Case Report presented when the Print Report link is selected does not present the primary email for the Case Manager when the Case Manager has more than one email. Should it present the primary email as it does in the Client Relationships Section of the report or is there a reason it presents a different email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug. If you look in CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php in getCaseRoles() it has this in the SQL:

LEFT JOIN  civicrm_email ON (civicrm_email.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id )

If you change it to

LEFT JOIN  civicrm_email ON (civicrm_email.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id AND civicrm_email.is_primary = 1)

does that fix it?